# Loop and render an object in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render an object inside an element (Panel element in `react-bootstrap`).

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Panel } from 'react-bootstrap';

const NetworkDetail = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      <Panel header="Network Details" bsStyle="info">
        {this.props.dataDetail && Object.keys(this.props.dataDetail).map(function(detail, id) {
            return <span key={id}>{this.props.dataDetail[detail]}</span>;
        }.bind(this))}
      </Panel>
    )
  }
})

export default NetworkDetail
```

But that doesn't work. The error thrown is

> **Uncaught Invariant Violation:** Objects are not valid as a React child
>   (found: object with keys {self}). If you meant to render a collection
>   of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using
>   createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method
>   of 'NetworkDetail'.

What I don't understand is that if I use

`return <span key={id}>{this.props.dataDetail.myProperty}</span>;`

it works.

How can I render all the properties and values of my object ?

Comment: Are you sure none of the keys in `props.dataDetails` might resolve an object in `this.props.dataDetail[detail]`?

Comment: Oh snap, the `dataDetail` object has actually a property named `_links` which is an object... (the app consumes a REST HATEOAS backend). If this `_links`object is the cause, how should I get rid of ? Maybe with underscore.js (I actually already use underscore.js to reformat my data) ?

Comment: You could use Underscore's `omit` function to filter `_links`. A better option might be to create a list of the keys you want to render and use Underscore's `pick` function instead. See: http://underscorejs.org/#omit

Comment: Thank you for your help. I accepted the answer below but you totally nailed the initial problem (the object inside my object). Thanks again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks to me that this component is a stateless/dumb component. So, you should begin by reading about how to write these kind of components to maximize efficiency: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions

Then, to fix your component, you should notice that

```
    {this.props.dataDetail && Object.keys(this.props.dataDetail).map(function(detail, id) {
        return <span key={id}>{this.props.dataDetail[detail]}</span>;
    }.bind(this))}
```

is just a conditional statement. Notice your '&&'. So, assuming that `this.props.dataDetail` is an object, you can rewrite this component like this:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Panel } from 'react-bootstrap';

const NetworkDetail = ({dataDetail}) => 
  <Panel header="Network Details" bsStyle="info">
    {
      Object.keys(dataDetail).filter(v => v !== '_links').map((detail, id) => <span key={id}>{dataDetail[detail]}</span>)
    }
  </Panel>

export default NetworkDetail;
```

Let me know if this works!

Comment: glad it worked out for you @Clafou. please let me know if you run into any other trouble =)